# Dynamic size check for iterators?

Tags: c++, iterator

```
vector<int> solution;
vector<int>::iterator col;
vector<int>::iterator row;
vector<int>::iterator sum;


...

for (row = vec.begin(); row != vec.end(); ++row)
{
    sum = solution.begin();

    for (col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); ++col)
    {
        if(sum == (solution.end())) //value for solution.end() doesn't change, while vector keeps growing
        {
            solution.push_back(*col);
        }

        *sum = (*sum + *col); //leads to segfault

        ++sum;
    }
}
```

I'd like to have a condition that allows me to check for growing vectors, but how the iterator is implemented in c++ as it doesn't allow me to do that. What should I use then?

Comment: `vector.size()` isn't sufficient?

Comment: maybe, but I don't think you can use it with sum. sum = solution.begin + n, while size is an integer between 0 and n. so are you suggesting me to use another variable x and increment it after ++sum and use vector.size()?

Comment: Your question isn't sufficiently clear.  "a condition that allows me to check for growing vectors" sounds as if you're trying to solve a race.  You probably want to use mutual exclusion to solve that problem.  Also, can you add the type declarations for `sum`, `solution`, `col`, et al?

Comment: hmmm didn't work, still getting segfault... yeah, i'll add it.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/6438087/489590

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(sum == (solution.end())) //value for solution.end() doesn't change, while vector keeps growing
{
    solution.push_back(*col);
}

else if(sum!=solution.end()) //<---- add this condition
    *sum = (*sum + *col);
```

`*sum = (*sum + *col);` this condition was executing even when sum reached to end result segmentation fault.

Comment: @user2967016 really? You can't upvote an answer to your own question?

Answer (score 1):

The `push_back` has the potential of invalidating all iterators into the vector; this explains why you're getting a segfault when you dereference `*sum` in the next line of code.

You can either recalculate `sum` by taking a difference from `begin()` and adding it to the new `begin()` after the `push_back()`, or you can use indices instead of iterators.

```
size_t offset = sum - solution.begin();
solution.push_back(*col);
sum = solution.begin() + offset;
```